# How to return the element in a vector satisfying some condition?(without 'if')

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I want to get `A'=[1 0 3 0]'` from `A=[1 10 3 100]'` from the below MATLAB code

```
new_A=A(A<10)
```

But it does not work.

I need to do this without `for` or `if`.

Comment: What language are you using? That would be a helpful detail to add.

Comment: just add it, do you know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(A < 10)` is a binary matrix of the same size as `A`. Thus this should do the job:

```
A .* (A < 10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess you are genius!

Comment: Technically `A<10` returns a logical matrix, which is represented as binaries. Good answer none the less